# TFS how to terminate/close a project

Tags: tfs

I am migrating from TFS to SVN, however want to keep TFS repository for reference. Is is possible to make the TFS project read-only? So no one can commit new changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right-click on the root folder for project in source control, and select 'lock'

Comment: This only locks the project while the "lock" is a pending change.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to change user permissions to read-only.